# How to assign hash with predefined hash value in Perl?

Tags: perl

Suppose i have a hash variable in a Perl script. I print its value in following way:

```
print \%MyHash;
```

and obtain following output:
HASH(0x33fa1fc)

I receive the same output consistently during many executions. For my prototyping purposes i would like to refer to this number in another script.

How can I do it? Should I try something similar to this?

```
my %MyHash;
$MyHash = Ox33fa1fc;
```

Comment: That number is the memory address of the data structure. It will change between process runs. If you see the same number, that's luck or coincidence. Referencing that number from another script makes no sense. If you want to copy data between two scripts, see [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html)

Comment: Why not save the address in a scalar variable `my $hashref = \%MyHash`?

Comment: @HåkonHægland jeg vil henvende meg til en bestemt minneadress i et annet script. Lagring er ikke noe problem. Takk for oppmeksomheten din.

Comment: @Kr.Sin You can also obtain the address using `refaddr` in [`Scalar::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util#refaddr)

Comment: Please communicate in English here.

Comment: If you use `Print \%MyHash`, the only output you will get is a syntax error. I expect you mean `print \%MyHash`. Please take more care over the information that you give us.

Comment: @DaveCross yes now i see it. Sorry but i have Print implemented on my own that is why it works for me. Sorry that made it unnecessarily dependent on my code base. I altered my question.

Answer (score 3):

The hex number is just the address where the hash variable happens to reside in memory. It can and will change with different releases of perl, and different releases of the operating system, or with minor changes in the execution of the code. It cannot be relied upon being the same across scripts, and perl provides no facility to convert an address back into a variable.

Comment: I clearly understand that this is very much inconvenient but i would like to know how can i refer to address in the memory. Thank you for your attention though.

Comment: @Kr.Sin Accessing the memory of another process depends very much on your operating system. Again, for copying information between processes, see `perlipc` or shmem or `mmap()`

Comment: Thank you Corion please what should i do with the question now? Delete it?

Answer (score 1):

It's the memory address of the hash.

For example,

```
use Devel::Peek  qw( Dump );
use Scalar::Util qw( refaddr );
my %h;
CORE::say(\%h);
CORE::say(sprintf("%x", refaddr(\%h)));
Dump(\%h, 0);
```

could output

```
HASH(0x1454af8)                   <-- The stringification of the reference.
1454af8                           <-- The address of the referenced variable.
SV = IV(0x1435eb0) at 0x1435ec0   <-- The scalar passed to Dump...
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)              <-- ...is a reference...
  RV = 0x1454af8                  <-- ...and this is the address of the referenced variable.
```

Since each process has its own memory space, this value is useless outside of the process that generated it. You can't build a reference that references this hash from another process (and it wouldn't be safe to have to processes accessing the same hash if you could).

---

> I receive the same output consistently during many executions.

By the way, there's no guarantee of that. In fact, it's not the case on my system.

```
$ for q in 1 2 3; do perl -e'my %h; CORE::say(\%h);'; done
HASH(0x100c878)
HASH(0x1a08758)
HASH(0x45a31e8)
```